# Get count of all duplicate values between two arrays

Tags: php

I am trying to get a count of all duplicate values between two arrays, I want to get the sum of all duplicate `array1` values which are present in `array2` value.

For example:

```
$array1 = array(1,3,2);
$array2 = array(1,1,1,2,3,3);
$count = count(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
```

The output must be: `6`

Comment: Why would the function output 6 and not 9? By my count every element in both arrays is duplicated in the other. What would the count be if one of the `1`s in `$array2` was changed to a `10`? 5, still 6, or 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly...

`array_sum(array_intersect($array1, $array2));`

Comment: He is referring to number of occurrences for each element of array1 with reference to array2

Comment: @PavanJiwnani but he says "the sum of all duplicate"

Comment: my bad I think its confusing

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reverse passed arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1,3,2);
$array2 = array(1,1,1,2,3,3);
$count = count(array_intersect($array2, $array1)); 

echo $count . PHP_EOL;
```

And result: `6`.

Comment: thanks brother , you are right ... problem in here `count(array_intersect($array2, $array1))`